# List of Lists Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have two classes:

```
public class One
{
    string PropertyA;
    string PropertyB;
    List<Two> ListOfClassTwo;
}

public class Two
{
    string MyString1;
    string MyString2;
}
```

How can i filter out the list in one query in the following way:

I still want to be able to access class One Properties and;
I want to filter the ListOfClass2 by say MyString1 == "Foo"

So i basically want to retain the class structure of class one itself, but filter ListOfClass2 to my liking.

I Should point out that class one, is actually in itself an enumeration
IEnumerable < One >

Thank you!

Comment: So what problems are you having writing that query?  What were your attempted solutions, and in what way did they fail to accomplish what you want?

Comment: Do you want to modify the contents of `ListOfClassTwo` in the original class `One` objects, or create new instances?

Comment: not related to your initial query, but should the properties be public ?

Comment: @juharr - Whatever will be of least overhead. I will be performing this operation 5 times a second, across hundreds of instances

Comment: @joe Yes. for brevity sake :) It's late and my brain has near on left the building, so hoping for a quick solution :D

Comment: @The_Chud Nobody is going to help you unless you show what you've tried already - this isn't a code writing service I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you only want to filter the inner lists and leave all items in the outer list as is if so ...

```
var listOfOnes = new List<One>() // assume this is populated with some stuff

var result = listOfOnes.Select(i => { 
     i.ListOfClassTwo = i.ListOfClassTwo
        .Where(j => j.MyString1 == "Foo")
        .ToList();
    return i;
});
```

... should do what you want.

Elaboration on the commented situation about mutating LINQ queries ...

if listOfOnes is passed in to a method that does the above then the parent scope (calling method) could be broken in some way as that scope is not expecting the other items that were filtered out to be filtered in that context.

A better solution might be something like ...

```
var result = listOfOnes.Select(i => { 
     var r = i.Clone();  
     r.ListOfClassTwo = i.ListOfClassTwo
        .Where(j => j.MyString1 == "Foo")
        .ToList();
    return r;
});
```

This would use a copy ctor to copy scalar only props on the "One" instance variable i inside the clone method and then provide a new filtered collection of children for that new One in the ListOfTwo's property.

Depending on the situation it may be prudent to use a bit of recursion here and deep clone the whole tree but it's hard to say what fits any given scenario without knowing more about the code wrapped around this statement.

Comment: Spot on! Thank you. I never would have got that tonight :)

Comment: Not sure what these down votes are about, I thought that was a pretty good question, a situation i've actually faced before too.

Comment: Mutating within Linq is a horrible idea.  This should be a `foreach` or if you want the `ForEach` method of `List` would even be better.

Comment: @juharr - please elaborate.  Why should we not mutate from within linq?

Comment: @Joe, just google "Linq side effects" and you'll find plenty of stuff about how Linq is not designed to have side effects occur within a query.

Comment: I think you're missing the point @juharr ... this is the objective, it answers the question and without knowing the context you can't make that call. In most situations however I would agree with you, it would make sense to construct a new list from the sub selection rather than manipulating the original, but that's not been asked. I was simply sticking to the question.

Comment: @War but you are mutating the objects in the original list.  The OP never even made it clear if that was desirable or not.

Comment: @juharr I have added a bit more elaboration to my answer as I do feel you have a point but I still don't know if that's intended / needed in this situation.